# Scale Invariant Statistical Distances

Tags: distance, metric

### Problem

Suppose we have empirical distributions to two $n$-dimensional random variables $X = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ and $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n)$. The goal is to find $k < n$ components, such that the $1$-dimensional distributions of $X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, ..., X_{i_k}$ and $Y_{i_1}, Y_{i_2}, ..., Y_{i_k}$ are "most similar" to each other, i.e. $\text{argmin}_i dist(X_i, Y_i)$.

We compare $X_1$ to $Y_1$, $X_2$ to $Y_2$ etc.

As an added difficulty due to physical units, the scale (max, min, std) of $X_i$ might be very differnt from the scale of $X_j$ for any $i \neq j$. But $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are approximately comparable (think same measurement device and test case but slightly different product).

### Question: What statistical distances are available that capture similarity between the components of $X$ and $Y$, are scale invariant and emphasize tail probabilities?

Our current aproach is as follows:

For each $i=1,...,n$

1. Take the Union $U_i$ over all samples from $X_i$ and $Y_i$
2. Compute $m = mean(U_i), s = std(U_i)$
3. $X_i' = (X_i - m) / s, \, Y_i‘ = (Y_i - m) / s$
4. $d(X_i, Y_i) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |p_i(x) - q_i(x)| |x|^p dx$ where $p$ denotes the PDF of $X‘_i$ and  and $q_i$ denotes the PDF of $Y‘_i$.

The factor $|x|^p$, ($p=5$) stems from the fact, that we don't really care about density around $0$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "counterparts"?

Comment: Ammended the sentence. For which i, Xi and Yi are the closest.

Comment: did you try K-S stat?

Comment: @Aksakal not yet.

Comment: Maybe that’s where you should start. It’s the common way to measure distance between distributions and its scale invariant

Comment: Unfortunately, the KS statistic does not focus on tail behavior and looks difficult to modify to make it so.  This is why other statistics, such as the [Anderson-Darling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) and [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) statistics, have been invented.  cc @Aksakal

Comment: @whuber right, so similar stats like AD should be a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a better answer incoming but here's something to get you started. It looks like what you're using is related to the [Total Variation Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures)

$$
\delta(P,Q) = \frac12 \int_{\mathbb{R}}|P(x) - Q(x)|\,dx
$$

(see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n) question for why this is the correct formula). This is unit independent since $P(x)$ is in units of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $dx$ is in units of $x$. It's also bounded between 0 and 1, making it a reasonable things to use to compare distribution over spaces with different units. The addition of the $x^p$ however will add in units and make comparison between the components $i$ and $j$ difficult.

If you want to keep the $x^p$ you could form a sort of "almost" $L^p$ metric using
$$
\delta(P,Q) = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|P(x) - Q(x)|^px^{p-1}\,dx\right)^{\frac1p}
$$

This will tend to emphasize values away from 0 more, but I would hesitate to say more about the behavior of the metric, or how to metric will change for different distribution, you could do some computational investigations though.

You can find a long list of metrics [here](https://statistik.econ.kit.edu/download/doc_secure1/3_StochModels.pdf) but no others jumped out at me as scale invariant.

Comment: Thanks, we already did some investigation into TV by setting p to 0 and that worked fine, although it would diverge from how engineering is using these densities. What exactly does x^(p-1) here?

Comment: Basically assume x is in units of meters $m$ as an example (in general an engineer of physicist might denote the units by [x]). It's not clear how to make sense of expressions with different units, is $10\,m<15\, s$ for example. As such, we only want to compare unitless quantities. In general, if $x$ has units $m$, than $x^2$ has units $m^2$, etc. A PDF $P(x)$ has units of 1/[x], since it takes an interval in [x] and returns a probability, which is unitless. $dx$ has units $[x]$, so $[\delta] = \frac{1}{[P(X)]}[x^p][dx] = [1]$ is unitless

Comment: It seems like you guys have put some good thinking into this, I would note that things being unitless doesn't mean they're on the same scale but for total variation that is fixed by the probability bound. So here, I'm just trying to create you another unitless quantity, I think it should work once you scale as you've done, but I'm not at all sure. Interesting question though!

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem interesting, too. It seems developing a sensible metric is a more difficult problem than we originally thought.

Comment: The rescaling before calculating the metric does not work in principle though, since we first scale both time series essentially based on their tails, then we estimate the size of exactly these rescaled tails. That's just circular logic.

Comment: I do think your rescaling is "correct" though, because you want to center your data and put it on the same scale for comparison. Can you generate a bunch of synthetic data in different situations and classify how things behave? It would be an interesting exploration of parameter space.